# Marginal effect of logit is larger than 1

Tags: logistic, mathematical-statistics

I guess this is more a math question than a statistics question. I do not understand how the value of a first derivative can be larger than the range of the original function. I must have a fundamental mistake but I fail to locate it.

The logistic CDF is $$\Lambda(X\beta) \in [0,1]$$ and in this case $$X\beta = \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_1^2x_2$$

Then the marginal effects of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are

$\frac{\partial \Lambda(X\beta)}{\partial x_1} = (\beta_1 + 2\beta_3x_1x_2)\lambda(X\beta)$

$\frac{\partial \Lambda(X\beta)}{\partial x_2} = (\beta_2 + \beta_3x_1^2)\lambda(X\beta)$

The R example below shows that there are many (82 out of 1000) cases where the first derivatives are larger than $\pm1$

```
set.seed(123);library(data.table)

n = 1000
b1 = .72
b2 = -.86 
b3 = 2.91

x1 <- rnorm(n = n, sd = 1)
x2 <- rnorm(n = n, sd = 1)

xb = (b1 * x1) + (b2 * x2) + (b3 * x1^2 * x2)

dx1 = (b1 + 2 * b3 * x1 * x2) * dlogis(xb)
dx2 = (b2 + b3 * x1^2) * dlogis(xb)

res <- data.table(x1, x2, dx1, dx2)
head(res[abs(dx1)>=1 | abs(dx2)>=1])

           x1          x2        dx1         dx2
1:  1.5587083 -0.01798024  0.1089530  1.21497093
2:  0.3598138  2.83222602  1.2401926 -0.09011081
3: -0.6250393 -1.64849482  1.3765467  0.05674045
4: -1.6866933  0.22855697 -0.3596850  1.75134047
5:  2.1689560 -0.26083224 -0.3165865  1.57885530
6:  0.6443765 -1.69186241 -1.4007296  0.08673243
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the values of a function are bounded, does not mean that its derivatives are bounded. Think about the function

$$
f(x)=\sin(1/x)
$$

Clearly bounded, isin't it? But guess what happens when you do $x\to 0$? The local variations and therefore the gradient will explode.

In fact, in the logistic regression there is no restriction on the parameter values $\beta_i$ so why should the expression $(a+\beta_i*x_j)*boundedterm$ be bounded?

The left-side multiplier can be anything.